# iOS swift share something on viber by clicking a button

Tags: ios, swift

In my ios application written in **swift** I want to generate a link based on a social network that user selects to share on.
For example if the user selects viber I want to know that. Is that possible? Is there an event or something?

Something like I provide a button which if the user clicks, it will open the viber with the generated link ready to be shared with friends.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you trying to generate a URL request to do the actual sharing, or are you trying to return a pointer to that shared information after the sharing operation is complete?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to generate a link like url?t=guid&sn=VIBER and share that in viber so basically I wanna open viber and share that link with it, I assume url schema should do it?

Comment: Ok, that's the "actual sharing" task. See below.

Answer (score 0):

The last time this came up, Viber did not have an API on iOS. I did not check for other platforms, but I seem to recall they don't have one for them either?

I believe they do have a sort of functionality for this through their web site, and you can likely hook that, but this will *not* be trivial. In the best case, you will need to send a series of URL requests with callbacks to do the "login" process and get credentials. In the worst case they will use session IDs that will lock you out between attempts.

I have two suggestions: 1) bug them for an API! 2) google up people doing this on Android. If you can find an example there you can likely port it with ease.

Comment: I actually did this myself on android, on my button for viber click i use action send for viber only with the specific link, is it possible to use url scheme for this matter on ios?